# Preparing Nested JSON array and retrieving it with jQuery $.each()

Tags: jquery, json

Since whole afternoon I am trying to send some JSON response and capture them as `select` options.
I have tried formatting JSON string in various ways to get it retrieved via nested `each()` function of jQuery but could not get it right.

Right now my code looks like this:

> Current JSON String Format:

```
 {
  "person1" : {"id":1, "name":"name1", "dob":"01-Jan-2016"},
  "person2" : {"id":2, "name":"name2", "dob":"02-Jan-2016"},
  "person3" : {"id":3, "name":"name3", "dob":"03-Jan-2016"},
  "person4" : {"id":4, "name":"name4", "dob":"04-Jan-2016"}
 }
```

I had also tried this format:

```
{
"persons" : [
    {"id":1, "name":"name1", "dob":"01-Jan-2016"},
    {"id":2, "name":"name2", "dob":"02-Jan-2016"},
    {"id":3, "name":"name3", "dob":"03-Jan-2016"},
    {"id":4, "name":"name4", "dob":"04-Jan-2016"}
  ]
}
```

> JQuery `$.get().done()` Handler:

```
var selectList = $("#personList");
var result = JSON.parse(data);
$.each(result, function(){
     $.each(this, function(key, value){
          alert(key + '=' + value);
          selectList.append($("<options />").val(name).text(value));
     });
 });
```

Now in the `alert` boxes I can get all the `key` and `value` pair, but I want the `<option>`'s value to be filled up by `person.id` and text by `person.name`.
Which is not happening.

May be my JSON array string format is itself not correct.

Can anyone please help me out with these two piece of codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the current JSON format, in the outer `$.each()`, `this` references the person object, e.g. `{"id":4, "name":"name4", "dob":"04-Jan-2016"}`, so you just need to access its properties:

```
 $.each(result, function(){
   selectList.append($("<option />").val(this.id).text(this.name));
 });
```

Alternatively, it is passed as the second parameter, like how had it in the inner `$.each`, so you can do this:

```
 $.each(result, function(key, value){
    selectList.append($("<option />").val(value.id).text(value.name));
 });
```

By the way, the tag is `<option>` not `<options>`.

Comment: Wow!! seems like you made my day!! :) Although my current JSON string format is good enough or the earlier one was better?? For now, I am getting the proper `<option>` tags with only one `each()` as you mentioned above.

Comment: Depends if you want to return other data in the JSON response. If not, the current format is smaller, so better

Comment: Thank you for prompt answer!